# DNS and Web servers on a single machine (same IP)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-registrar, resolve, name

I have a server with DNS and IIS7.5 installed. I also own a domain xyz.com (fictitious name, of course). 
How do I setup DNS to resolve to machine's IP for this domain provided DNS is installed on the same machine and is reached thru the same interface? 
In other words, how do I set my DNS server to be reached by other DNS servers (located elsewhere) so that it can resolve my domain to my IP? Is this possible? Shall I do something with the domain name registrar (it is enom.com)? Like denote my DNS as an authoritative server for my domain?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly. You have to create NS records (and glue records) at the registrar that designate your server as the name server for your domain.